# how to post multi files and file-descriptions in one form correctly?

Tags: python, html, forms, post

i'm trying to post multiple files with in one form like this:

```
  <form method="post">
  name1: <input type="text" name="e-jp-title" class="e-form-jp-input" /><br /> 
  file1:<input type="file" name="e-jp-img" /><br />
  url 1:<input type="text" name="e-jp-link" class="e-form-jp-input" />

  name2: <input type="text" name="e-jp-title" class="e-form-jp-input" /><br /> 
  file2:<input type="file" name="e-jp-img" /><br />
  url 2:<input type="text" name="e-jp-link" class="e-form-jp-input" />
  </form>
  ......
```

and i want to use python to handle these file posts.if all the names are same,i can use

```
   e-jp-titles = request.form.e-jp-title
   e-jp-imgs = request.form.e-jp-img
   e-jp-links = request.form.e-jp-link
   result = zip(e-jp-titles, e-jp-imgs, e-jp-links)
```

to get all the informations,but if the user do not finish some information in the form,for example,if the first e-jp-link is None,the final result will be uncorrect,so ,how to handle the informations correctly or how to design the form so i can get all the correct informations?

Answer (score 1):

Well, HTML is mainly useful for the look and appearance which are static by nature. If u want any validations or retrieve information one may use javascripts or any other that is comfortable(like you are using Python here).All validations like the a text is not entered or String is entered where a number is expected etc. are all handled in the logic part that is dynamically done which is python here.Hence there is nothing you can do from HTML part except for designing it attractively.All you can do is validate the HTML page in python using validations as already described above.Hope it helps.